# Redirect all URLs in a folder and exclude a URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am redirecting everything (including all URLs following the forward slash) from this URL/folder: `/forums`
to this URL: `/blog/`
using this code that is currently working:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forums https://www.website.com/blog/
```

but I want to exclude this URL:

```
/forums/8/is-dermarolling-an-effective-treatment-for-hair-loss-1953
```

and then redirect it to another URL of the website:
`/use-this-example/`

right now it obviously also redirecting to `/blog/`

Answer (score 0):

First you must exclude this line `/forums/8/is-dermarolling-an-effective-treatment-for-hair-loss-1953` from the rule and that what i did so, put this code at your main directory `.htaccess` and put in front of every line of your previous code `#` to be disabled then run this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/8/is-dermarolling-an-effective-treatment-for-hair-loss-1953
RewriteRule ^forums/(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,R=302]
```

If it is Ok , change `302` to `301` to be permanent redirection

> Update

According to your comment that you want only to override every request including /8/ put the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/8/
RewriteRule ^forums/(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: thank you, your code it redirecting to /blog/ but the URL is not excluded and redirect to blog as well,  your code didn't work at first, by the way, you didn't remove the forward slash from /forums ,I did this: RewriteRule ^forums(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,R=302]

Comment: do you have any thing else at 8 directory ?

Comment: you can replace this line with this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/8/           up to directory 8 , try it then tell me

Comment: The problem is that I have several URLs like that, some start with /8/ and some will use other numbers like /3/

Comment: Ok, make sure this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/8/is-dermarolling-an-effective-treatment-for-hair-loss-1953 you put / before forums as what i sent

Comment: i did, here is my code: 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/8/is-dermarolling-an-effective-treatment-for-hair-loss-1953
RewriteRule ^forums(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,R=302]'

Comment: there is also / after forums in here missing RewriteRule ^forums/(.*)$

Comment: I have copied your code, it is redirecting both the /8/ URL and the /forums/ URL to /blog/ , I want everything to redirect to /blog/ following /forums/ except the file that begins with the /8/

Comment: I made file like what you wanna excluded and it is excluded for me

Comment: Man, the URL is like that: https://www.website.com/forums, without the forward slash...so your code doesn't redirect /forums to blog/, it redirects /forums/ to /blog/ and it keeps all other urls from redirecting too

Comment: see what you wrote in question , /forums/8/is-dermarolling-an-effective-treatment-for-hair-loss-1953

Comment: So I guess maybe I wasn't clear enough sorry, I want ANY URL that comes after /forums/ to redirect to /blog/ except the /8/ URL I provided...on top of that I have this URL: /forums (no forward slash) that needs to also redirect to /blog/

Comment: Thank you, Mohammed. your code didn't work but it led me to the solution...so in the end you helped me and i thank you for that. the code that is working is: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/8/
RewriteRule ^forums blog/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Ok , wish you all the best

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mohamed that direct me, here is the solution:

```html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/8/
RewriteRule ^forums blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```